# Can the linked duplicate question on a closed question be changed afterwards?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186626/what-are-the-reasons-that-keep-manuscript-status-as-manuscript-submitted-over) was recently closed as a duplicate of the canonical "Journal Workflow" question. Yet, when looking into it due to it being in the "reopen" cue, I think there are some better candidates that this question is a duplicate of, e.g. [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/paper-with-editor-for-longer-than-two-and-a-half-months) or probably even better, [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/is-my-paper-under-review-or-similar-for-too-long-and-if-yes-how-should-i-reac) (created as a result of [this meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/do-we-want-a-canonical-question-for-general-journal-workflows)). The question is now: is there a way to switch the linked duplicate question on an already closed question, or do we have to reopen and then vote to reclose the question suggesting a different duplicate? (Which feels quite like a complicated detour)

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that closed questions with no answers are likely to be [automatically deleted by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/). So this problem is usually worth solving only if the question saw lots of activity before being closed (and if the current duplicate target is extremely bad, not merely suboptimal).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the second canonical question is a better duplicate target, so I’ve changed it.

About the process:

1. Yes, once a question is closed, to change the closure reason or the duplicate target, standard users have to first reopen the question and then reclose it. Since this requires five votes for each part of the process, it can be difficult to achieve. [Moderators and gold tag-badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/300001) can instead edit the duplicate target directly.
2. Multiple duplicate targets can also be added by moderators and gold tag-badge holders without the need of reopening the question. However, in this particular case, I thought it was better to change the duplicate target altogether, rather than adding the new one.

Comment: "Moderators and gold tag-badge holders can instead edit the duplicate target directly."  Is it better to post on  meta or to raise a flag?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist For clear-cut cases a flag is enough.